# Convert serial port returned byte to millisecond

Tags: c#

Hey guys, here's my issue. Working with the iPort... one of the commands to send through the serial port is getplaystatus and 4 bytes are returned to describe the length of the song in milliseconds. An example is a song as 4:39 to it... the length returned from is an array

byte[] b = {0x00, 0x04, 0x67, 0x83};

So 4:39 in milliseconds is 279000.

Somehow those bytes need to equal 279000... and I've run out of ideas. Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks!

~Marty

Comment: Are you sure it's 4:39 and not really 4:48?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, it's actually 288643. It's actually 4:49, isn't it?

You use the BitConverter class to convert them, but you might need to reverse them first:

```
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
  Array.Reverse(b);
}
int ms = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);
```

Comment: That works... I was confused at first because i was taking 4 and making it 240000 and then 39 and making it 39000 then adding the values up to get 279000... which is my bad. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
(((((b[0] * 10) + b[1]) * 60) + (b[2] * 10) + b[3])) * 1000
```